# vsftpd allow full access in selinux

Tags: centos, vsftpd

When I try to alow full access to FTP, suing the `setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access 1`
I am getting this error:

libsemanage.get_home_dirs: insta homedir /var/www/html or its parent directory conflicts with a file context already specified in the policy.  This usually indicates an incorrectly defined system account.  If it is a system account please make sure its uid is less than 500 or its login shell is /sbin/nologin.

I am very new to Linux and I have no idea how to proceed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to browse vsftpd with setenforce 1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67386/unable-to-browse-vsftpd-with-setenforce-1)

Comment: Please don't repost your question, edit the original one ;-)